# create json object from other json objects

Tags: java, json

I have two json objects -- not strings, please -- that I want to combine into one json object as shown below.

The two objects:

```
JSONObject pen = {"plastic":"blue"}
JSONObject book = {"Maya":"Bird"}
```

Desired result:

```
JSONObject bag = {"plastic":"blue","Maya":"Bird"}
```

Is there an elegant way to do this? I mean without extracting the values of each `pen` and `book` and then re-insert them into `bag` using something like

```
bag.put("plastic","blue");
```

I am using `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject` if that information is necessary.

Comment: How would you expect it to handle conflicts if both JSONObject's have the same key attribute?

Comment: So something like [`jQuery.extend(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)?

Comment: `JSONObject pen = {"plastic":"blue"}` - is that really valid Java code?

Comment: A would be elegant solution is `bag.accumulate("bag",pen); bag.accumulate("bag",book);`. But the result would be an array: `{"bag":[{"plastic":"blue"},{"Maya":"Bird"}]}`, which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Naively, it seems like you could just do something like:

```
Iterator it = pen.keys();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    String k = it.next();
    bag.put(k, pen.getJSONObject(k));
}
// bag now has the combined key,value pairs.
```

But it has its obvious limitations.